# Python Paths - ImportError: cannot import name 'dataset_builder'

Tags: python

I am getting an error `ImportError: cannot import name 'dataset_builder'`. The import command is following:

`from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder`

The file tree looks following:

```
-ObjectDetection
   -train.py     
   -models
     -research
       -object_detection
          -builders
             - __init__.py
             -dataset_builder.py
```

I am running the `train.py` from the root directory (os.getcwd() returns following path `C:\Users\horakm\PyCharmProjects\ObjectDetection`) and I added in the `train.py` following code to add paths:

```
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\horakm\PyCharmProjects\ObjectDetection\models')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\horakm\PyCharmProjects\ObjectDetection\models\research')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\horakm\PyCharmProjects\ObjectDetection\models\research\slim')
```

When I print all paths using `sys.path` i get this:

```
   ['C:\\Users\\horakm\\PyCharmProjects\\ObjectDetection', 
'C:\\Users\\horakm\\PyCharmProjects\\ObjectDetection', 
'C:\\Users\\horakm\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\envs\\tf1_env\\python36.zip', 
'C:\\Users\\horakm\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\envs\\tf1_env\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Users\\horakm\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\envs\\tf1_env\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\horakm\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\envs\\tf1_env', 
'C:\\Users\\horakm\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages', 
'C:\\Users\\horakm\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages\\win32', 
'C:\\Users\\horakm\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\horakm\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 
'C:\\Users\\horakm\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\envs\\tf1_env\\lib\\site-packages', 
'C:\\Users\\horakm\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\envs\\tf1_env\\lib\\site-
packages\\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg', 
'C:\\Users\\horakm\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\envs\\tf1_env\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 
'C:\\Users\\horakm\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\envs\\tf1_env\\lib\\site-
packages\\win32\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\horakm\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\envs\\tf1_env\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 
'C:\\Users\\horakm\\PyCharmProjects\\ObjectDetection\\models', 
'C:\\Users\\horakm\\PyCharmProjects\\ObjectDetection\\models\\research', 
'C:\\Users\\horakm\\PyCharmProjects\\ObjectDetection\\models\\research\\slim']
```

**How is it possible that the import statement doesn't work?**

Comment: where is this test.py and are you getting import error in test.py or train.py?

Comment: @suvy ohh sorry there is no test.py. There is only train.py.

Answer (score 0):

Which object are you actually trying to import?

- All that are defined in dataset_builder? In that case it should be `from object_detection.builders.dataset_builder import *`.
- Or is the object also called dataset_builder? In that case it is `from object_detection.builders.dataset_builder import dataset_builder`.